# Aquiring a Dutch Passport - married for 30 years

Tags: netherlands, passport, eu-family-member

My husband of 30 years has a Dutch Passport, my two sons as well.  We lived in The Netherlands from October 1992 - September 1995. We went back to South Africa in 1995.  Can I apply for a Dutch passport even if we are not living in The Netherlands (We live in SA).  I have a 5 year Visa allowing me to be in the 90 out of 180 period.  My sons live in the Hague for 6 months of the year (Husband has rented an apartment).  We travel quite often and the 90/80 day is becoming a problem. Do the 3 years we lived here in 1992 count at all in my favour?

Comment: I do not think so. See [Becoming a Dutch citizen](https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-citizenship/becoming-a-dutch-citizen)

Answer (score 1):

The qualifications for naturalizing as the spouse or partner of a Dutch national are listed at [Can I become a naturalised Dutch citizen abroad?](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/dutch-nationality/becoming-dutch-national-naturalisation)  Among them is a requirement not to live in your country of nationality.  Therefore, if you are a South African citizen, it seems that you won't qualify.  The full list is

> - you are 18 or older
> - you have passed the naturalisation test
> - you are not a national of the country where you live
> - you meet the conditions for a Dutch residence permit for non-temporary purposes of stay
> - you have not committed a criminal offence in the past 5 years
> - if necessary, you are prepared to renounce your current nationality
> - you are prepared to attend the naturalisation ceremony and take the citizenship pledge.

I believe the renunciation of your current nationality is not required because you are the spouse of a Dutch national, but I'm not sure about it.

In any event, you see that it might be possible in your case but it would require an investment of a good deal of time.

You should also be aware that as the spouse of a Dutch citizen, you are entitled to stay with your Dutch husband in any other EU or Schengen country without regard to the 90/180 rule and with very few administrative requirements.  For more information, see [the summary](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/LSU/?uri=celex:32004L0038) or [the directive itself](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02004L0038-20110616).